# How do I counter drop shot and lob shot?

Tags: mario-tennis-aces

So I know that a fully charged topspin, slice and flat would add significant knockback if you don't return it with the proper shot, but I was just in a game where my opponent was doing the same with drop and lob shots. I had no idea this was even possible, and despite trying seemingly every shot type, it didn't seem to prevent the knockback.

How do I counter drop and lob shots?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Prima](https://www.primagames.com/games/mario-tennis-aces/tips/mario-tennis-aces-shot-counters) (aka those folks who make all the strategy guides), the **Drop Shot** is countered with a **Top Spin**, and the **Lob Shot** is countered with a **Flat**. The reason I likely had trouble figuring out the shot counter is due to a misunderstanding of how the counter system works. It doesn't prevent all knockback, it just   reduces it:

> The only way to avoid a ton of push back when trying to return these shots is to use the appropriate counter shot. Every basic shot type has a specific counter. While your character will still get pushed back a bit, it won’t be nearly as much as if you didn’t use the correct counter.